# How can I generate an image, sliding like a progress bar?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I apologize now for my poor English.

I need to display a "digitalized image" of the readings of two IR sensors, mounted one on top of each other. Imagine the single read as 2 blocks, again on top of each other, colored as the "presence" or "absence" of an object in front of the upper and lower sensor. This sort of block of image should be rendered on the app, effectively recreating what the sensor have red.

In the next reading I want the previous block to shift, making space for the new one. The image should "keep generating itself" as new readings are made. I'd like to have a hundred blocks from side to side of the screen. You could call what I want to make a sort of "double progressbar", bottom half for the readings of the bottom sensor, upper half for the readings of the upper sensor. I'm using an Arduino which sends via Bluetooth 3 different signals ("a"=object absent; "b"=object only bottom; "c"=object on both sensors).

Comment: Hi Davide, SO is typically here to help you solve code errors.  You should try to make the progress bar yourself first.  If you run into trouble, post a question with specific code for us to look over, we're here for you!

Comment: Sorry but i don't know where to start. I looked for tutorials or guides but nothing. I can't put images in a row and edit them in such a way that simulates the progression of an image nor i can't edit the canvas element in any way. At this point I think I'll give up the idea, it was an optional point of a project. I'll just leave this question up  for a few days, in case someone has some advice for me.

Comment: you might want to ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) for suggestions...